# Python class multiple constructors

Tags: python, class, oop, constructor

There is a class that I want to be constructed from a string in 2 different ways. Here is what I mean:

```
class ParsedString():

    def __init__(self, str):
         #parse string and init some fields

    def __init__2(self, str):
         #parse string in another way and init the same fields
```

In Java I would provide a private constructor with 2 `static` factory methods each of which define a way of parsing string and then call the private constructor.

What is the common way to solve such problem in Python?

Comment: (it is not a constructor, but a `initializer`. Note that it receives `self` , so it must have already been constructed )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in java:

```
class ParsedString():

    def __init__(self, x):
        print('init from', x)

    @classmethod
    def from_foo(cls, foo):
        return cls('foo' + foo)

    @classmethod
    def from_bar(cls, bar):
        return cls('bar' + bar)


one = ParsedString.from_foo('!')
two = ParsedString.from_bar('!')
```

docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod

There's no way, however, to make the constructor private. You can take measures, like a hidden parameter, to prevent it from being called directly, but that wouldn't be considered "pythonic".

Comment: Looks like the solution works both for python 2 and python 3. Thanks